# How to resolve a form before use

Tags: filenames, eval, forms

I have a form variable which contains a list of file paths specified via functions:

```
(defcustom my-files-form
      '(append (list (concat my-root ".emacs")
                     (concat my-root ".custom"))
               (file-expand-wildcards (concat my-elisp "user-lisp/[a-z]*.el")))
      "My Form"
      :type 'string)
```

Before I use the form in a `tags-search` I want to filter the form's file paths by `seq-filter` (specifically `(seq-filter 'file-exists-p my-files-form)`).

However I  get an error `"Wrong type argument: stringp, append"` when doing so. I guess this happens because `my-files-form` is not yet a proper list of paths but the *instructions* to generate the list of paths.

How can I resolve these instructions into a proper list?

Comment: @phils Makes sense! Thanks. Will try it out.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @drew Thanks for hint about the `elisp` tag.  (However I feel dumping the URL in the comments section without further remarks is a little bit terse given a community which wants to be friendly...)

Comment: @phils Works perfectly!  Thanks a lot. -- Would you mind turning your comment into an answer? If you mind, I'm happy to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```el
(seq-filter 'file-exists-p (eval my-files-form))
```

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `eval`

Also note that variables which are going to be `eval`'d should have a `risky-local-variable` property -- but as this happens by default for a variable name ending in `-form` (amongst other things), you don't need to do anything additional in this instance.